# Branch.io referral implementation not working in web app

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, branch.io, referrals

I am using branch SDK in the mobile app for which I am working on for more than 2 years now. I want to have the referral feature in our web application as well. I have followed the web app integration guidelines and has integrated branch in my app. I am using v2.54.2 of branch SDK and v16.13.1 of React.

I am facing a strange issue after integrating. I am calling the `branch.logout()` method while the user logs out of the application. But after the user logs in back (either to the same user account or to a different user account in our application), none of the branch functionalities work. (`branch.setIdentity()`, `branch.credit()`, `branch.redeem()` etc.). I am getting the following error in the console

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON string: [object Object]
    at ia (build.min.js?cd67:7)
    at d (build.min.js?cd67:57)
    at Mb (build.min.js?cd67:57)
    at eval (build.min.js?cd67:146)
    at eval (build.min.js?cd67:135)
    at k (build.min.js?cd67:66)
    at XMLHttpRequest.Sb.g.onreadystatechange (build.min.js?cd67:64)
```

I’m not even able to identify which method is causing this error. The branch APIs won’t work even if I do a hard reload. After days of debugging what I found is all the functionalities will work if I open the app in a new tab and close the current tab. But if the user logout and login from the new tab, the issue comes back.

What I suspect is the global branch object, while logging out is not getting reset to the initial state. Can anyone please help me with this issue? I am stuck with this issue for more than 2 weeks now

Comment: Hey, Arun we have replied to this query on the ticket raised with us.

Comment: @KartikShandilya can you please check the issue quickly. I am using Branch in my production application as well. From last week, the production application also stopped working. It is not rewarding referral balance to the users anymore